What does $\cos \operatorname{am} $ mean?
I know about $\cos x$ and $\cosh x$. What is $\cos\operatorname{am} x$? It appears in Charles Hermite’s correspondance, but appears out of nowhere. Seems like common notation of the period. Looking for a definition or identity.


The folks at the dedicated History of Science and Mathematics SE might have some insights.

Perhaps amplitude?  (The French spelling is the same as the English one.)

This is the Jacobi Amplitude

It could be helpful to others to say this comes from volume 3 of Hermite's Works from a letter "On the Pendulum"

It's the Jacobi amplitude. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_elliptic_functions#Definition_in_terms_of_inverses_of_elliptic_integrals

Winner winner chicken diner. You hit the nail on the head. Thank you.
